# Re-start jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item1').delay(1000).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(1000).addClass('animated bounceInUp'); 
    });

    $('.item2').delay(2000).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(2000).addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
    });

    $('.item3').delay(2500).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(2500).addClass('animated fadeInUp'); 
    });

    $(".item1, .item2, .item3").hide(); 
});
```

**I want to restart again when the animation ends.** so The animation must be continuous. without end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to run your code once every second or so.

```
window.setInterval(function(){

$('.item1').delay(1000).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(1000).addClass('animated bounceInUp'); 
    });

    $('.item2').delay(2000).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(2000).addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
    });

    $('.item3').delay(2500).fadeIn(1,function(){
        $(this).delay(2500).addClass('animated fadeInUp'); 
    });

    $(".item1, .item2, .item3").hide(); 

},1000);
```